# react redux non smooth UI performance

Tags: performance, reactjs, user-interface, redux

Our app is being developed with React and Redux and we are experiencing an issue i would love for you to advise on.
I am in the process of improving performance, and the first thing on my mind is making the UI smoother.
We feel in many cases that the UI is not smooth and snappy, things feel stuck.
Let me give a concrete example - we have a TimeSelectionButtonBar component which allows you to change the time range of data presented in a highcharts graph.
here is a gist : https://gist.github.com/sht5/dcca86afd74a6f820ebe150ba777b425
[image]

As the currently selected time range is relevant to the highcharts graph we keep it in the store, and its current value is connected to this TimeSelectionButtonBar component, determining it's currently active button.
when someone clicks a time range button, what happens is :

1. We fire an action to change the currently active time range in store.
2. The TimeSelectionButtonBar component's prop changes as a result of the action and changes the active (blue) button in it's UI.
3. A thunk action is fired getting data data for the graph according to selected time range
4. A "data received" action is fired and the graph updates.

The problem is - there is a lag when re-rendering the TimeSelectionButtonBar component and the change in active button is not smooth.
What i think is happening here actually is that the component doesn't manage to finish re-rendering before the next action starts. it's important to state that currently our graph rendering takes a while for different reasons.

After this realization i tried moving the thunk action call to the TimeSelectionButtonBar component's componentDidUpdate method but this doesn't solve the issue.
the following stackoverflow conversation suggests either using setTimeout or window.requestAnimationFrame to delay the thunk, making time for the component to finish updating but this seems like a hack and doesn't seem to always work.

Answer (score 0):

after debugging i found there was a lot of code running within the selectors and i was using reselect. Also, the massive usage of the ImmutableJS library and specifically the fromJS and toJS functions in reducers caused the issue. after removing them and using reselect correctly performance improved amazingly